# A query to return a single attribute of a document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, subdocument

```
[ "_id" : ObjectId("59d1f4d0539f772aacf90f61"), 
    "user_id" : 1222.0, 
    "user_name" : "jadenn", 
    "email" : "jdkdkdjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjh@j.com", 
    "phone" : 333333333.0, 
    "image_ref" : "static/image/123IMG_20170917_232813.jpg", 
    "stories" : [
        {
            "title" : "accident", 
            "description" : "kjsbskns", 
            "longitude" : 19.2, 
            "latitude" : 81.4, 
            "location" : "isl", 
            "date" : 12.0, 
            "reactions" : [
                {
                    "type" : "seen", 
                    "date" : "1234", 
                    "user_id" : 123.0
                }, 
                {
                    "type" : "seen", 
                    "date" : "1234", 
                    "user_id" : 123.0
                }
            ], 
            "comments" : [
                {
                    "comment" : "djksnjknfkjguye", 
                    "date" : 123.0, 
                    "user_id" : 123.0
                }, 
                {
                    "comment" : "this is the accident case ", 
                    "date" : 123.0, 
                    "user_id" : 123.0
                }
            ], 
            "reports" : [
                {
                    "description" : "uye", 
                    "date" : 123.0, 
                    "user_id" : 1232321.0
                }
            ], 
            "catagory_name" : [
                {
                    "type" : "uye"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my document I want a query which will return only list of stories. Not a complete document of user. I searched but could not find the solution. Every solution return complete document by applying "Where condition as MYSQL"][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msdNZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to project on `stories` key from your document as below:

```
db.youCollection.find({}, {stories:1, _id:0})
```

Comment: I only need list of stories. But it is returning complete user details.

Comment: did you try to project only stories?